# How to store object data in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I keep doing google of how to store object data in Laravel.

I have an Model object which is using among functions and the Model data will not be changed indeed. So I want to store it into the global area for access.

I think it should be stored in something like the ServletContext(Application Scope) in tomcat. But I can't find such concept in Laravel at all.

Could anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store it for the current session, just store it in session. That will be the easiest way to share it between methods.

Comment: Thank you. But all sessions will use the same data object so don't want to waste the resource.